# Lenovo ubuntu 18.04 L450s won't come out of the Standby mode

Tags: 18.04, suspend, power-management, lenovo, battery

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad L450swith ubuntu v18.04 on it. When I started the laptop a few hours ago, it hanged on the login screen. I thus long-pressed the power button to restart the system.
However, since then, no matter how long or how many times I press the Power button, the laptop won't come out of sleep mode.

When I say sleep, the power button keeps blinking.
Approaches I have tried so far:

1. Remove battery, long-press the power button to discharge it completely. Then, connect the charger and press the power button to switch it on: Same result as above.
2. Remove battery, connect the charger and press the power button to switch it on: Same result as above.

Please suggest how can I make it come out of this sleep/standby mode.

Right now, I have kept the battery removed and connected it to my charger.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try closing and then opening the screen which should bring it out of standby mode.  I've occasionally seen something like this on another Lenovo
laptop and this technique brought it back.

If it used to work and now doesn't the switch triggered by the lid could be broken since when the lid is closed, it will stay in standby mode.  If it's a new installation, check your BIOS settings and power configuration settings.